# How can i process single frames of h.264 raw in python

Tags: python, objective-c, socket.io, video-streaming, h.264

I have an Objective-C app  thats connects to python server throw Socket.IO,
i currently sends h264 raw frames throw socket and receive them in the Python side, but i dont know how to proceed from there, 
i have tried to use numpy and cv2.imdecode to convert the byte frame for process and none of those helped me. 
i also tried Ffmpeg but i am new to this library and maybe someone can put a light on it.

the end goal is to process this frames for object-detection, and restream them to the web.

the frame sends as singles each times.

```
    -(void)videoFeed:(DJIVideoFeed *)videoFeed didUpdateVideoData:(NSData *)videoData {
[[DJIVideoPreviewer instance] push:(uint8_t *)videoData.bytes length:(int)videoData.length];
[_videoExtractor parseVideo:(uint8_t *)videoData.bytes length:(int)videoData.length withFrame:^(VideoFrameH264Raw *frame) {
```